# Integerating phonegap with eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I am new to phonegap.I am trying to integerate phonegap with eclipse for android application.

I had followed this tutorial  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html

When i gone through beginners tutorial i found that i have to add cordova-x.x .jar file to libs folder in eclipse. I had downloaded phonegap 2.9.2 from phonegap site and unzipped the package but i cannot find cordova.jar file in the android folder.
Do i have to download the cordova.jar from seperate website.
It will be very helpful if your providing some help....

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

you can download it here... It would help you

```
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi use latest version of cordova (3.4), instal using CLI tool, in latest version cordova.jar replaced by cordova subproject [ projectName -CordovaLib (sub project)] [image],  check this for phonegap CLI [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface).

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `JAR` file, you can build it manually from the cordova-android source code:

```
$ cd ~/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/framework
$ android update project -p 
$ ant jar
```

> => ~/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/framework/cordova-3.3.0.jar

**Btw:** Why you are using an old version?